# Jackson deserialize Joda DateTime from Unix format

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

When deserializing from JSON I have dates that are written in Unix Epoch time (/Date(1379542610387+1000)/).

I understand that is it pretty standard to serialize dates in Json this way, however how can I get this value deserialized into a Joda DateTime?

When jackson see's a value like this it spits out:

```
Invalid format: "/Date(1379542610387+1000)/"
```

Comment: If that's really what the date looks like (is +1000 the UTC offset in hours and minutes?) you will have to read it as a String and parse and interpret it yourself.

Comment: The thing between the quotes is exactly pulled from a response from an API. I believe the +1000 is the UTC offset (Australian Eastern Standard time). I've seen this format in a few API Json responses and am not terribly keen to string.split it into pieces.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((\d+)[\\+\\-](\\d+)\\)/");

...

String data = "/Date(1379542610387+1000)/";
Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);
if (m.matches())
{
    long time = Long.valueOf(m.group(1));
    int  offset = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
    System.out.printf("time=%d offset=%d\n",time,offset);
}
else
    // not a date in the recognized format ...
```